# what is alternative for AggregationOutput to perform lookup operation in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

**Collection** = c_1, c_2
I want to perform lookup operation using **groovy language** in mongodb. I successfully created match, lookup, and project operation. But I am facing error in **AggregationOutput**.

```
c_1.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "lastName" : "kumar",  "companyId": 10]))  
c_2.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 10, "companyName" : "Microsoft", "numEmployee" : 100 ]))  
// Successfully created the $match operations
// Successfully created the $lookup operations  
// Successfully created the $project operations  
List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, lookup, project);  
AggregationOutput output = c_1.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Error:**   Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DBCollection JavaDoc](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.11.4/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate(com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject...))

```
public AggregationOutput aggregate(DBObject firstOp,
                      DBObject... additionalOps)
```

you cannot pass [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to that function, you need to do something like:

```
AggregationOutput output = c_1.aggregate(pipeline.get(0), pipeline.get(1), pipeline.get(2));
```

Check out [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article to learn more about MongoDB load testing using JMeter.

Comment: I'm not gonna keep an eye on your post and refresh it daily in order to check for updates and amend the answer as original context will be lost. Consider asking a new one instead.

Comment: Thanks, Problem solved. Original context is restored.